# As of today 03/24/2017 what versions of Cucumber Java are out there

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

The information on the net is a little misleading but here is what I was able to find out.
A stable implementation of Cucumber is the 1.3.15.
The stable Java implementation is 1.2.5.

Is there is already a 2.4 version of Cucumber or just the version of the second edition of the book is in 2.4 (https://cucumber.io/blog/2017/02/28/the-cucumber-book-second-edition)?

Is there any 3.0 version of Cucumber?
And if it is where can I find information about it?

Comment: Down-voted since *"this question does not show any research effort"*, given that answer is available on the [Cucumber web site](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm), or rather the [public maven repo](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/cukes/cucumber-java8/) or [latest snapshot version](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/pom.xml) linked from there.

Comment: Well I did my research but Stackoverflow did not allowed me to add more links, like this one: https://rubygems.org/gems/cucumber/versions/3.0.0.pre.1

Comment: That looks very Ruby specific, and you're asking about Java, so what does that link have to do with your question about Java?

Comment: Well maybe someone out there started to port the newer versions of Cucumber to Java or you still can use some parts of those versions under Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I can not post links, because I do not have enough reputations, so links to my findings will be missing or maybe posted as text.

After searching more and asking in friendlier forums, here is what I was able to find out.
Cucumber Java (1.2.5) moves very differently (and much slower) than Cucumber Ruby (2.4). Also a coincidence the main Ruby version is at 2.4 just as the Cucumber Ruby version.

Well, Ruby version is much more faster and here it is:
'Imagine link here to the Ruby history'
'Imagine link here to the Java history'

Regarding features available in the Ruby version versus the Java versions I have no idea. Java users should stay content what they get from Aslak Hellesøy.

I am still having problem understanding the following link: 
'Imagine link to a Ruby Cucumber 3.0 version'

But I guess that belongs to the Ruby community and nobody here cares...
I also was able to understand the 'Imagine link to a Gherkin 4.0 version'